How to use COMPRESSION_ADOBE_DEFLATE instead of DEFLATE?
When converting to PDF using ddjvu:
ddjvu -format=pdf input.djvu output.pdf

there is a warning:

TIFFWriteDirectorySec: Warning, Creating TIFF with legacy Deflate codec identifier, COMPRESSION_ADOBE_DEFLATE is more widely supported.

How can I use COMPRESSION_ADOBE_DEFLATE instead of delfate?
I tried
ddjvu -format=pdf -quality=COMPRESSION_ADOBE_DEFLATE input.djvu output.pdf

but though -quality=deflate works, -quality=COMPRESSION_ADOBE_DEFLATE and its variations (e.g., AdobeDeflate) returns the error message:

ddjvu: valid arguments for option '-quality' an integer between 25 and 150.


I’m voting to close this question because it is crossposted: https://superuser.com/questions/1845191/how-to-use-compression-adobe-deflate-instead-of-deflate

You can, of course, but I never understood why some people bother about cross-posting so much. If I get the answer in one place, I will immediately delete the copy of the question, of course (if there won't be any answers there yet, and this is exactly how it usually happens). And of course, this will be unfriendly, because there is no guarantee I will be able to get help at Superuser. And so I will end up without the answer.

@jsx97 you can’t know when you delete your question whether someone isn’t already working on an answer. You’d just end up wasting their time.

@StephenKitt There are still no answers neither here, nor at Super User. I just deleted the copy of the question at Super User and opened a bounty here.

That warning is output by libtiff since this commit from 2021-05-08 (see corresponding pull request; commit included in 4.4.0 and above).
As of 2024-06-11, looking at the source, DjVuLibre has no support for using COMPRESSION_ADOBE_DEFLATE.
As you mentioned it on their forum, which was the best thing to do in this instance, that may raise their awareness that "COMPRESSION_ADOBE_DEFLATE is more widely supported" if they didn't already and that may change in the future. You could also raise a feature request ticket or even bug one as that warning could be seen as undesirable.

Many thanks, Stéphane! I just asked a related question, maybe you know the answer to that too? https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/778227
