ddjvu: using '-quality' option with values higher than 100
I try to figure out how to use ddjvu to convert DjVu files to PDF. If I use
ddjvu -format=pdf input.djvu output.pdf

the output PDF is very huge and consists of lossless images. Also, there appears a warning, which I will talk about later:

TIFFWriteDirectorySec: Warning, Creating TIFF with legacy Deflate codec identifier, COMPRESSION_ADOBE_DEFLATE is more widely supported.

To make the output file smaller and to consist of lossy images, man ddjvu suggests to use the -quality option:

-quality=factor: Enables lossy JPEG compression for TIFF and PDF files. This option only affects images that cannot be encoded using the preferred TIFF/G4 compression.  Argument factor is a quantization factor ranging from 25 to 150. See command cjpeg(1) for more information on JPEG quantization factors. Value 80 is a good starting point.

If I use values up to 100 (e.g., 80, 90, or 100),
ddjvu -format=pdf -quality 90 input.djvu output.pdf

the TIFFWriteDirectorySec warning doesn't appear. To my understanding, this is because using -quality means that PDF will consist of lossy images, which in turn means that it will consist of JPEGs instead of TIFFs.
But if the value is higher than 100, e.g. 105 or 150, the warning appears again. Why is that?

Compression quality settings are roughly a percentage between 0 and 100.  To quote the man page for cjpeg mentioned in the link above:

For this purpose the quality setting should be between 50 and 95; the default of 75 is often about right. If you see defects at -quality 75, then go up 5 or 10 counts at a time until you are happy with the output image. (The optimal setting will vary from one image to another.)
-quality 100 will generate a quantization table of all 1's, minimizing loss in the quantization step (but there is still information loss in subsampling, as well as roundoff error). This setting is mainly of interest for experimental purposes. Quality values above about 95 are not recommended for normal use; the compressed file size goes up dramatically for hardly any gain in output image quality.

A quality setting of 100 means to attempt to achieve the best results possible while still using a lossy encoding.  Anything above 100% is asking for something impossible (better than original quality) and invalid input. ddjvu is therefore just ignoring your quality setting if set above 100.

I'm really not sure this is true because man ddjvu suggests to use values up to 150.

It looks like in the source code https://github.com/traycold/djvulibre/blob/master/tools/ddjvu.cpp quality between 0-100 gives JPEG compression.  somehow quality of 900 is deflate compression and 901 is lzw compression.  I haven't found the rest of the command line parsing code to see how 101-150 is converted into those yet.

Well, thanks! This is bad it is documented so poorly.

I think I figured it out:  if you set the options for LZW or deflate it stores those results as 900/901 quality and 1000 quality if uncompressed.  Then it parses the quality level if those aren't set.  It limits that number for between 25 and 150 for no logical reason, and then it only does jpeg compression if it's between 0 and 100.  I have misgivings about the maintenance of this tool.
